# Как составить Makefile для openvc?

Tags: c, opencv, gcc, makefile

В общем создал на QtCreator-е (в QtCreator-e всё собираеться :3 ), но потом от меня потребовали сделать через `Makefile` на `gcc` без QtCreator-а

вот мой **Makefile** :

```
# стандарт по-умолчанию вашего проекта
CS = c11
# имя компилятора
CC = gсс
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib
OBJECTS =
LIBRARIES = -fopencv_core -fopencv_imgproc -fopencv_highgui

.PHONY: all clean

all : test

test:
    $(CC) $(LIBRARIES) $(CFLAGS) main.c -o tream 

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

**main.c**

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        // задаём высоту и ширину картинки
        int height = 620;
        int width = 440;
        // задаём точку для вывода текста
        CvPoint pt = cvPoint( height/4, width/2 );
        // Создаёи 8-битную, 3-канальную картинку
        IplImage* hw = cvCreateImage(cvSize(height, width), 8, 3);
        // заливаем картинку чёрным цветом
//        cvSet(hw,cvScalar(0,0,0));
        // инициализация шрифта
        CvFont font;
        cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1.0, 1.0, 0, 1, CV_AA);
        // используя шрифт выводим на картинку текст
        cvPutText(hw, "OpenCV Step By Step", pt, &font, CV_RGB(150, 0, 150) );

        // создаём окошко
        cvNamedWindow("Hello World", 0);
        // показываем картинку в соз0данном окне
        cvShowImage("Hello World", hw);
        // ждём нажатия клавиши
        cvWaitKey(0);

        // освобождаем ресурсы
        cvReleaseImage(&hw);
        cvDestroyWindow("Hello World");
        return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/openvc2$ make 
gсс -fopencv_core -fopencv_imgproc -fopencv_highgui -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib main.c -o tream 
make: gсс: Command not found
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

Не знаю что я делаю не так всё перепробовал, ничего не выходит.

---

Спасибо саше баракину :3

Исправил я **Makefile** :

```
# стандарт по-умолчанию вашего проекта
CS = c11
# имя компилятора
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/opencv -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
OBJECTS =
LIBRARIES = -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui

.PHONY: all clean

all : test

test:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o test test.c $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

также переименовал `main.c` в `test.c`

Вот вывод который он мне дал :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/openvc2$ make
gcc -I/usr/include/opencv -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o test test.c -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
/tmp/ccrnMYT4.o: In function `cvPointFrom32f':
test.c:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `cvRound'
test.c:(.text+0x56d): undefined reference to `cvRound'
/tmp/ccrnMYT4.o: In function `cvReadInt':
test.c:(.text+0xe74): undefined reference to `cvRound'
/tmp/ccrnMYT4.o: In function `cvEllipseBox':
test.c:(.text+0x10dc): undefined reference to `cvRound'
test.c:(.text+0x10fe): undefined reference to `cvRound'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: `gсс: Command not found` — перевод требуется?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так что сделать надо ???

Comment: установить пакет, содержащий программу gcc. обычно он называется точно так же.

Comment: `CC = gсс` — у вас тут кириллица вместо латиницы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin обновил вопрос

Comment: задайте лучше новый вопрос (а этот удалите), в котором выбросьте все упоминания про make[file] (как не имеющие отношения к делу). оставьте в нём только то, что начинается со слов «вот вывод который он мне дал» — тут более чем достаточно информации. или лучше сами для начала поищите (хоть в гугле, хоть на этом сайте), что значит «undefined reference to» и как с этим быть.